# How to use the "number_to_currency" helper method in the model rather than view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use `to_dollar` method in my model like this:

```
module JobsHelper      
  def to_dollar(amount)
    if amount < 0
      number_to_currency(amount.abs, :precision => 0, :format => "-%u%n")
    else
      number_to_currency(amount, :precision => 0)
    end
  end      
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  include JobsHelper
  def details
    return "Only " + to_dollar(part_amount_received) + 
           " out of " + to_dollar(price) + " received."
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, the `number_to_currency` method is not recognized here:

> undefined method `number_to_currency' for #<Job:0x311eb00>

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It’s not available because its use in a model (typically) violates MVC (and it does seem to in your case). You're taking data and manipulating it for presentation. This, by definition, belongs in the view, not the model.

Here are some solutions:

- Use a presenter or view model object to mediate between the model and view. This almost definitely requires more initial work than other solutions, but is almost always a better design. Using helpers in a presenter/view-model doesn’t violate MVC, as they reside in the view layer, replacing traditional custom Rails helpers and logic-filled views.
- Explicitly `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` in `JobsHelper` instead of depending on Rails to have magically loaded it for you. This is still not great, as you shouldn’t access a helper from a model.
- Violate MVC & [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). See [fguillen’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5867154/211563) for how to do this. I won’t echo it here because I don’t agree with it. Even more so, though, do I disagree with polluting your model with presentation methods as in [Sam’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5176750/211563).

If you think “but I really need this to write my `to_csv` & `to_pdf` methods in my model!”, then your entire premise is wrong—after all, you don’t have a `to_html` method, do you? And yet your object is very often rendered as HTML. Consider creating a new class for generating your output instead of making your data model know what a CSV is ([because it shouldn’t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

As for using helpers for ActiveModel validation errors in the model, well, I’m sorry but ActiveModel/Rails has screwed us all there by forcing error messages to be realized in the data layer, rather than returning the semantic *idea* of an error to be realized later—*sigh*. You can get around this, but it basically means not using ActiveModel::Errors anymore. I’ve done it, it works well.

As an aside, here’s a useful way to include helpers in a presenter/view-model without polluting its set of methods (because being able to do e.g. `MyPresenterOrViewModel.new.link_to(...)` makes no sense):

```
class MyPresenterOrViewModel
  def some_field
    helper.number_to_currency(amount, :precision => 0)
  end

  private

  def helper
    @helper ||= Class.new do
      include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
    end.new
  end
end
```

Comment: I usually follow this rule but break it when I need a view helper to format a validation error message defined in the model.

Comment: Rails collection select helpers do not respect MVC because they want to perform a model instance method on the selectable item to determine what to display.  So in that case you can hack around the framework or violate MVC.

Comment: This is good advice, but it's a bad answer because it does not solve the question.

Comment: There are cases where this is not a great answer, for instance right now where I am buiding a csv report and need to use something like this in a to_csv method in a class that will never see a view. Just sprouting programming ideals is not always helpful.

Comment: Yea, what nitecoder said.  I'm running into the same issue.  I'm generating PDF reports and simply want to nicely format a phone number.

Comment: In the case of render a JSON, what is the best way to use this helpers? In that case I don't have a view, my "view" is the JSON. I'm using a serializer, I've put the helper on that, but I needed to `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`. Is the correct way?

Comment: I'm using Prawn to create a pdf, which happens in the controller. In order to have a nicely formatted percent value on my pdf, I need to put the number_to_percentage in the controller, not the view.

Comment: I realize the _official_ answer to the scenarios people mention about generating csv, pdf, or json output is to use views for each of those. But I still agree with @nitecoder. If the only formatting to be done is to make a few numbers into currency, adding a view just over-complicates things. Maybe that leaves a helper as the proper home for such operations.

Comment: Also, this answer's reference to the single responsibility principle seems not to apply if the responsibility of the model is something like reporting.

Comment: @maurice It’s a slippery slope from “well just this one thing” to a bloated model. App helpers in Rails are a junk-drawer, presenters/view-models are easier to manage. I don’t see creating the *data* for a report and generating the (html|pdf|csv|etc.) *view* of that data as a single responsibility any more than I do for, e.g., a person and an HTML person show page.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question.

Comment: Note: this solution would also be applicable for an `ActiveModel::Serializer` where the resource is instantiated in a controller that does not have a `view_context` (i.e., `ActionController::API`).

Comment: I'm a bit tired of reading the comments "Don't do this in a model". There are lots of valid use cases where due to some business requirement it makes perfect sense to request these helpers (generating PDF via Prawn for example). If you are a beginner, just build something that works and don't worry too much about clean code or advice that limits you.

Answer (score 197):

I agree with all of you that this could be breaking the MVC pattern but there is always reasons to break a pattern, in my case I needed these *currency formatter methods* to **use them in a template filter** (*Liquid* in my case).

At the end I found out I could access to these *currency formatter methods* using things like this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency
```

Comment: This is good, though there is a slightly cleaner way of doing it. See [http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views](http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views)

Comment: Yay comment track in RailsCasts: In Rails 3 in 2013, using a View helper in a Controller is done like view_context.number_to_currency(amount)

Comment: Have you thought about using the "money" gem?  As money object provides a format() method, and you can invoke it in the model, controller, or view.

Answer (score 92):

I know this thread is very old, but someone can look for solution for this problem in Rails 4+. Developers added ActiveSupport::NumberHelper, which can be used without accessing view related modules/classes using:

```
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_currency(amount, precision: 0)
```

Comment: This approach worked for me when I wanted to experiment with the behavior of `number_to_percentage` in the Rails console. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

You need to also include the ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  include JobsHelper
  def details
    return "Only " + to_dollar(part_amount_received) + 
           " out of " + to_dollar(price) + " received."
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but I have to agree with others that say I violate the MVC. I'll put `details` in the helper.

Comment: Helpful if you are like Florent2 and need to put it as part of a validation message. Thanks Sam.

Comment: This worked for me. I don't think it makes sense to always follow MVC (or any principle) if a solution that violates that principle is clearly better than one that adheres to it.

Comment: This approach is not recommended. It adds a lot of methods which you don't need, and it clutters up your namespace, it may overwrite some methods, and some helper modules rely on other helper modules (so you may need to include multiple modules), thereby making the issue even worse. For an explanation and better approach, see: [http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views](http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views)

Answer (score 6):

Piggybacking off of `@fguillen`'s response, I wanted to override the `number_to_currency` method in my `ApplicationHelper` module so that if the value was `0` or `blank` that it would output a dash instead.

Here's my code in case you guys would find something like this useful:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def number_to_currency(value)
    if value == 0 or value.blank?
      raw "&ndash;"
    else
      ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(value)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just `include ActiveSupport::NumberHelper` module, if you don't need additional features defined by `ActionView`.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/44260581bec06e4ce05f3dd838c8b4736fc7eb1d/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb#L383

Answer (score 4):

You can use `view_context.number_to_currency` directly from you controller or model.

Answer (score 3):

@fguillen's way is good, though here's a slightly cleaner approach, particular given that the question makes two references to `to_dollar`. I'll first demonstrate using Ryan Bates' code (http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views).

```
def description
  "This category has #{helpers.pluralize(products.count, 'product')}."
end

def helpers
  ActionController::Base.helpers
end
```

Notice the call `helpers.pluralize`. This is possible due to the method definition (`def helpers`), which simply returns `ActionController::Base.helpers`. Therefore `helpers.pluralize` is short for `ActionController::Base.helpers.pluralize`. Now you can use `helpers.pluralize` multiple times, without repeating the long module paths.

So I suppose the answer to this particular question could be:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  include JobsHelper
  def details
    return "Only " + helpers.to_dollar(part_amount_received) + 
           " out of " + helpers.to_dollar(price) + " received."
  end

  def helpers
    ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice but it works for me!

to import include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper in the controller. For example:

```
class ProveedorController < ApplicationController
    include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
    # layout 'example'

    # GET /proveedores/filtro
    # GET /proveedores/filtro.json
    def filtro
        @proveedores = Proveedor.all

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # filtro.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @proveedores }
        end
    end

    def valuacion_cartera
        @total_valuacion = 0
        facturas.each { |fac|
            @total_valuacion = @total_valuacion + fac.SumaDeImporte
        }

        @total = number_to_currency(@total_valuacion, :unit => "$ ")

        p '*'*80
        p @total_valuacion
    end
end
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

Really surprised not one person has talked about using a Decorator. Their purpose is to solve the issue you are facing, and more.

https://github.com/drapergem/draper

EDIT: Looks like the accepted answer basically did suggest doing something like this. But yeah, you want to use decorators. Here's a great tutorial series to help you understand more:

https://gorails.com/episodes/decorators-from-scratch?autoplay=1

P.S. - @excid3 I accept free membership months LOL

Answer (score -5):

Helper methods are generally used for View files.
It is not a good practice to use these methods in Model class.
But if you want to use then Sam's answer is ok.
OR I suggest you can write your own custom method.

Comment: This is not an answer.