# undefined method `number_to_currency' for "2000":String:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, getter-setter

I want to put prices with decimals, instead of being just integers.

I'm trying to use a getter and setter methods in order to update the inputs value to currency before saving to ddbb.

This are my methods:

```
before_validation :format_price

def format_price
  self.min_price
end

def format_price=(amount)
  self.min_price = amount.number_to_currency
end
```

This is my input:

```
<%= f.input :format_price %>
```

My column in my model is called `min_price` and it's an integer column (where I want to save the new value).

The problem comes when I put 2000 as a price and save, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `number_to_currency' for "2000":String:
```

Why is this happening? I can't get it to work.

Thank you

Comment: Because you're calling it with a string parameter?

Comment: Please read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176718/how-to-use-the-number-to-currency-helper-method-in-the-model-rather-than-view) and use it in the proper place.

Comment: But where is that specified?

Comment: It is a view helper method, you shouldn't call it inside the controller.

Comment: I'm not touching the controller, only using model and view

Answer (score 4):

This method is defined in `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper#number_to_currency`. It gives you an hint that it should be used only in the context of a view.

Using it from a model violates the separation of concern. It's not the responsibility of your model to format data.

This should be done either in the view, or using a presenter when things get messy in the view.

```
<%= f.input :format_price, value: number_to_currency(instance.format_price) %>
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for the response. The thing is, since my column is an integer, if I put that helper on view, it will still be saved as an integer. So thats why I need to use virtual attributes to change the value, Im so stuck with this.

Comment: why can't you store it as a float ?

Comment: Because I've read floats math is not accurate with prices. How about :decimal type?

Comment: Why not, but definitely not string