Why is the data in a Rails view displaying as 0.0 or 42.0 instead of $42.00?
Question Title: Why is the data in a Rails view displaying as 0.0 or 42.0 instead of $42.00?
Summary: How can I get this field to display e.g. $42.00 instead of 0.0 or 42.0?  In addition to the display format, it also needs to be in a data type on which I can perform math operations such as sum and average. How do I do that?  I can get it to work in Rails Console, but not in the app.
Constraints: I have to fix this in Ruby on Rails, not in Excel.
Question:
I am a relatively inexperienced programmer.  At work I am helping develop an app to deal with book purchase requests using Ruby on Rails.  I did not create it, but I am updating it.
I am importing data from a csv file.  The csv file has a field called "us_list".  When I display it in the view, it shows as 0.0 or 42.0 instead of $42.00.  This is because in the csv file the field is a string which looks like " $42.00 ".  Note the whitespace on each side.  I need to be able to manipulate the financial data, using sums, averages, etc. I understand I shouldn’t use Floats for currency.  I found two possible solutions:  number_to_currency and monetize.
Monetize works the best.  In my file app/services/slips_csv_import_service.rb, I added:
load '~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2@pda/gems/money-6.19.0/money.gemspec'
load '~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2@pda/gems/monetize-1.13.0/monetize.gemspec'
load '~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2@pda/gems/money-rails-1.15.0/money-rails.gemspec'


To process the us_list field, I did this:
us_list = " $42.00 "  # test code, not in production
temp1 = row[:us_list].strip
temp2 = temp1[1..]
slip_hash{:us_list] = Monetize.parse(temp2).format 


If the field value is, e.g. " $42.00 ", it displays as 0.0.  If I delete the .format, it displays as 42.0, which is at least an improvement.
slip_hash[:us_list] = Monetize.parse(temp2)

If I go into Rails Console, and I type
us_list = " $42.00 "
temp1 = us_list.strip
temp2 = temp1 [1..]
Monetize.parse(temp2).format


It displays "$42.00", which is correct.
I also tried number_to_currency. I put the include statements at the top of the same file above.  I’m doing a shorter version of the assignments to save space
I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176718/how-to-use-the-number-to-currency-helper-method-in-the-model-rather-than-view,
include ActiveSupport::NumberHelper
slip_hash[:us_list] = number_to_currency("42")

The output is 0.0 in the app.  If I do the following in the rails console
include ActiveSupport::NumberHelper
number_to_currency("42")

It displays "$42.00", which is correct.
I found this: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html,
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
slip_hash[:us_list] = number_to_currency("42")

The output is 0.0 in the app. If I do the following in the rails console
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
number_to_currency("42")

It displays "$42.00", which is correct.
The monetize code also gives me an error message in Rails Console:
[WARNING] The default currency will change from `USD` to `nil` in the next major release. Make sure to set it explicitly using `Money.default_currency=` to avoid potential issues
[WARNING] The default rounding mode will change from `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` to `ROUND_HALF_UP` in the next major release. Set it explicitly using `Money.rounding_mode=` to avoid potential problems.
[DEPRECATION] You are using the default localization behaviour that will change in the next major release. Find out more - https://github.com/RubyMoney/money#deprecation.

I therefore added the following code at the top of the file:
#https://github.com/RubyMoney/money#deprecation
Money.locale_backend = :i18n
I18n.locale = :en
  
#https://rick-moore.medium.com/formatting-number-strings-in-ruby-4da35d5282e3
Money.rounding_mode = BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_EVEN
#Money.locale_backend = :currency
Money.default_currency = "USD"

And I ran into some problems making the require/load work:
For some reason I couldn’t get
require ‘money’
require ‘monetize’ 

to work.  I tried a lot of combinations and found the load statements above by trial and error and googling. I’m including this info in case it’s impacting the rest of my code.
More info:
Language Version:

Rails 7.0.3
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (on Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit)
Database: sqlite3, 1.4.2
I am using the local version – the development version is not deployed.  I’m using Chrome Version 126.0.6478.183 (Official Build) (64-bit)
I am writing my code in Visual Studio Code v 1.91.1
EDIT
Here is the code from show.html.erb
<% @title = "Book Slip ##{@slip.id}" %>

<table class="rvt-table-stripes">
  <caption class="rvt-sr-only">Book Slips details</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Field names</th>
      <th scope="col">Values</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
[snip]
<% unless @slip.us_list.blank? %>
  <tr>
    <th><%= t 'slip.label.us_list' %></th>
    <td><%= @slip.us_list %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
[snip]
  </tbody>
</table>

I am pulling the value of [:us_list] from a CSV file.  For debugging purposes, I tried using the value of "$42.00" or 42 instead of pulling the data from the csv file.

You say "The output is 0.0 in the app." a bunch of times but I don't see anywhere in the post that shows the implementation in the app (I am assuming a view). The closest example shows row[:us_list].strip but does not show what this value is. Also those load statements don't make any sense. Is the monetize gem in your Gemfile?

Are you importing the Gems in your gemfile? you don't need those files loads.

It is in my gemfile:
gem "monetize", "~> 1.13" / gem "money", "~> 6.19" / gem 'money-rails', '~> 1.12'

I took out the load statements and it did not affect the result.
The error message I got for `require 'monetize'` was `cannot load such file`. Oddly enough, I tried it one more time this morning, and I did not get any error messages.  So I guess this part is resolved.

I put the response to the question about the implementation in an edit in the body.

I got the answer outside of Stack Overflow:
In app/services/slips_csv_import_service.rb
slip_hash[:us_list] = row[:us_list].gsub(/[^\d\.]/, '').to_d

In app/views/slips/show.html.erb
<%= number_to_currency(@slip.us_list, unit: '$') %>

Now the field displays correctly as e.g. $42.00 or $24.95
